# importing a python module in an app engine project causes server error 500

Tags: python, google-app-engine, wsgi, webapp2

in my app engine project, I have a folder called "crawl" which has python modules (has `__init__.py` too). when I import a module in the class that handles requests, it causes server error 500.

this import `from crawl.crawler import Crawler` allows the post function defined in the request handler class to create an object of the class Crawler. 
I'm using the webapp2 framework.
I hope my question is clear. thanks

Comment: What do the App Engine logs say about that 500 error? They should show exactly what exception you're getting and where in your code it's triggered.

Comment: thanks so much... I totally forgot about the logs. It's working now

Comment: always happy to help!